# Xamarin.Forms Datepicker NullReferenceException ios 9.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, datepicker, xamarin.ios

I've added Datepicker control in my view. All works as expected on iOS version higher than 10.0.

But on iOS 9.0 Datepicker throws NullReferenceException.

Does anyone know how to prevent this exception?

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: When does this happen? What are the exception details?

Comment: @FreakyAli Added details to question

Comment: Post the code in Custom Renderer and share project .Maybe you called some API which is available after iOS 10.0 .

Comment: Can you share the code in the picker selection change event? Also share the Xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already a known bug in Xamarin Forms GitHub.
[link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6946). So the problem in XF Renderers.

As a solution, I implemented my own Renderer for Pickers and add null check

```
if (entry.InputAssistantItem != null)
{
    entry.InputAssistantItem.LeadingBarButtonGroups = null;
    entry.InputAssistantItem.TrailingBarButtonGroups = null;
}
```